# Undefined Control Sequence on \onehalfspacing

Tags: line-spacing

I am new to latex. So new that I never heard of this a month before.

I am using wissdoc.cls, macros.tex, titelseite.tex and diplarb.tex from the following [template](http://tm.uka.de/~bless/wissdoc.tar.gz).

I have an error as follows:

```
l.135 \OnehalfSpacing
            % 1,5 Zeilenabstand}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

I heard somewhere that changing the spelling from `onehalfspacing` to `OneHalfSpacing` would make the error go away. Please help me fix this.

I am willing to add more data if required.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The package `setspace` lets you easily change the line spacing, and that provides a macro `\onehalfspacing`. Hence, add

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
```

Answer (score 13):

For those of you using the `memoir` document class, the fix involves disemulating the `setspace` package first, as outlined [here](http://greengabbro.net/2009/02/15/line-spacing-with-the-latex-memoir-class-why-doesnt-setspacesty-work/):

```
\DisemulatePackage{setspace}
\usepackage{setspace}
% \onehalfspacing, etc.
```

Comment: Note that `memoir` include similar features as `setspace` and actually implements some of it better

Comment: @daleif This may be the case, but I suspect a lot of people like myself are tired of CTRL+F:ing the tome that is the Memoir manual.

Comment: THANK YOU. REALLY.

Comment: The corresponding memoir commands are `\OnehalfSpacing` and `\DoubleSpacing`.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem and whatever I did to fix the issue it didn't work. The reason was that the packages had conflict with "**setspace**". On the other hand, without using the "**setspace**" package, the **\onehalfspacing** macro didn't work properly (although it didn't complain, but the spacing was not as it was supposed to be).

I ended up using another solution which worked perfectly:

```
\linespread{1.3}\selectfont{}
```

This makes the spacing 1.5 times the normal spacing. If you want normal or double spacing, you can use values 1 and 1.6 respectively.

PS: For tables, figures and footnotes, you can add a smaller spacing in their block (e.g., between **begin{table}** and **end{table}** statements). This does not affect the spacing outside those blocks.

Also if you want, you can change the spacing from place to place:

```
\linespread{1.3}\selectfont{}
%one and half spacing
...

\linespread{1}\selectfont{}
%one
...

\linespread{1.6}\selectfont{}
% double spacing
```

but note that from the place you choose the last specified spacing to the end of the document, that spacing will be in effect.

If you want a specific spacing in the whole document, put your desired one right after **begin{document}**.